# Assign a value to vector in a for loop versus a closure in Rust

Tags: for-loop, rust, closures

Im am wondering how to assign a value to an element within a vector in a closure.

This code works ...

```
let mut vec1 = Vec::<i32>::new();
vec1.push(1);


for num in &mut vec1 {
  *num = 0;
}
```

So the question is how to do the same in a closure. I have tried so many variants but none did work. This is the basic code, but where do I have to use & or mut or both of them or none of them?

I would have assumed that the following code is equivalent to the one above, but it does not work. I tried several other variants like for_each(|&num| or for_each(|mut& num| but none of them work.

So this is the closure I am thinking about, but it does not compile.

```
&mut vec1.iter().for_each(|num| {
  *num = 9;
});
```

This also does not work for example ....

```
vec1.iter().for_each(|&mut num| {
  *num = 9;
});
```

And so on ...

I'm lost (and quite new to Rust).

Comment: I don't think you *should* be doing this, but if it's just for practice, then you're looking for `vec1.iter_mut()`

Comment: Yes, now this works as I would have assumed. And yes, it is for practicing Rust.

I am wondering why you say that using a closure is not suggested rather than using the for loop.